# Parse.com and Chrome Packaged Apps

Tags: parse-platform, google-chrome-app

This question was already asked in the old Parse.com help forums :

https://www.parse.com/questions/parsecom-javascript-api-and-chrome-packaged-apps

Has there been any progress on adapting the parse js.sdk to be compatible with Chrome Packaged Apps ???

In particular it seems to fail on this line :

```
    var userData = Parse.localStorage.getItem(Parse._getParsePath(
      Parse.User._CURRENT_USER_KEY));
```

with the following error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
```

Comment: I have no idea parse js.sdk can be compatible with Chrome Packaged Apps. But you can use `chrome.storage` to get an API with similar features: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: It seems you just can't use parse in chrome app unless you change how parse sdk works... I really have no idea and looking for an answer